# delete line when breaking pivot high

Tags: pine-script

I took an open script for ABCD harmonics, using arrays to store different zigzag-lengths. After the ABCD is plotted, I added a line at the top. Now I want to remove/change the line, when prizes breaks the line.
It looks like I cannot "catch" this line to delete it. (code line 200).

Can you help me out?

Best
Thom

Code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
indicator('ABCD Scanner', shorttitle='ABCDs', overlay=true, max_bars_back=490, max_lines_count=490, max_labels_count=490)
//Define Groups
grp_c1 = "©"
grp_c = "BOX 4 Functions"
grp_zz = "Zigzag Settings"
grp_pattern = "ABCDs"
grp_color = "Color Settings"

max_pivot_size = input.int(490, step=10, group=grp_c1) 

zigzag_mult = input.int(3, step=1,minval=1,group=grp_zz)
zigzag1Length = input.int(1, step=1, minval=1,group=grp_zz)
showZigZag1 = input(true,group=grp_zz, inline="zz1", title="Zig Zag 1")
zigzag1Color = input(color.new(color.teal,50),group=grp_zz, inline="zz1", title="")
zigzag1Width = 1
zigzag1Style = line.style_solid

showZigZag2 = input(true,group=grp_zz, inline="zz1", title="Zig Zag 2")
zigzag2Length = zigzag1Length+zigzag_mult*1
zigzag2Color = input(color.new(color.olive,50),group=grp_zz, inline="zz1", title="")
zigzag2Width = 1
zigzag2Style = line.style_solid

showZigZag3 = input(true,group=grp_zz, inline="zz2", title="Zig Zag 3")
zigzag3Length = zigzag1Length+zigzag_mult*2
zigzag3Color = input(color.new(color.lime,50),group=grp_zz, inline="zz2", title="")
zigzag3Width = 2
zigzag3Style = line.style_solid

showZigZag4 = input(true,group=grp_zz, inline="zz2", title="Zig Zag 4")
zigzag4Length = zigzag1Length+zigzag_mult*3
zigzag4Color = input(color.new(color.fuchsia,50),group=grp_zz, inline="zz2", title="")
zigzag4Width = 2
zigzag4Style = line.style_solid

abcdClassic = input(true,group=grp_pattern, inline="row13",title="ABCD")

errorPercent = input.int(3, minval=3, step=1, maxval=20, group=grp_c)

waitForConfirmation = input(false)

// Colors
bullishColor = input(color.new(color.green,85), title="Label bullish", inline="cc01")
bearishColor = input(color.new(color.red,85), title="Label bearisch", inline="cc01")

err_min = (100 - errorPercent) / 100
err_max = (100 + errorPercent) / 100

var zigzagpivots1 = array.new_float(0)
var zigzagpivotbars1 = array.new_int(0)
var zigzagpivotdirs1 = array.new_int(0)

var zigzagpivots2 = array.new_float(0)
var zigzagpivotbars2 = array.new_int(0)
var zigzagpivotdirs2 = array.new_int(0)

var zigzagpivots3 = array.new_float(0)
var zigzagpivotbars3 = array.new_int(0)
var zigzagpivotdirs3 = array.new_int(0)

var zigzagpivots4 = array.new_float(0)
var zigzagpivotbars4 = array.new_int(0)
var zigzagpivotdirs4 = array.new_int(0)

var wmlines1 = array.new_line(19)
var wmtype1 = array.new_int(2, 1)
var wmLabels1 = array.new_bool(4, false)
var wmlabel1 = array.new_label(9)

var wmlines2 = array.new_line(19)
var wmtype2 = array.new_int(2, 1)
var wmLabels2 = array.new_bool(4, false)
var wmlabel2 = array.new_label(9)

var wmlines3 = array.new_line(19)
var wmtype3 = array.new_int(2, 1)
var wmLabels3 = array.new_bool(4, false)
var wmlabel3 = array.new_label(9)

var wmlines4 = array.new_line(19)
var wmtype4 = array.new_int(2, 1)
var wmLabels4 = array.new_bool(4, false)
var wmlabel4 = array.new_label(9)

pivots(length) =>
    float phigh = ta.highestbars(high, length) == 0 ? high : na
    float plow = ta.lowestbars(low, length) == 0 ? low : na
    dir = 0
    iff_1 = plow and na(phigh) ? -1 : dir[1]
    dir := phigh and na(plow) ? 1 : iff_1
    [dir, phigh, plow]

zigzag(length, zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs) =>
    [dir, phigh, plow] = pivots(length)
    dirchanged = ta.change(dir)

    if phigh or plow
        value = dir == 1 ? phigh : plow
        bar = bar_index
        newDir = dir
        if not dirchanged and array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 1
            pivot = array.shift(zigzagpivots)
            pivotbar = array.shift(zigzagpivotbars)
            pivotdir = array.shift(zigzagpivotdirs)
            useNewValues = value * pivotdir < pivot * pivotdir
            value := useNewValues ? pivot : value
            bar := useNewValues ? pivotbar : bar
            bar

        if array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 2
            LastPoint = array.get(zigzagpivots, 1)
            newDir := dir * value > dir * LastPoint ? dir * 2 : dir
            newDir

        array.unshift(zigzagpivots, value=value)
        array.unshift(zigzagpivotbars, bar)
        array.unshift(zigzagpivotdirs, newDir)

        if array.size(zigzagpivots) > max_pivot_size
            array.pop(zigzagpivots)
            array.pop(zigzagpivotbars)
            array.pop(zigzagpivotdirs)

detect_harmonic_pattern(zigzagpivots, zigzagpivotbars, zigzagpivotdirs, wmlines, wmlabel, wmtype, wmLabels, zigzagColor, zigzagWidth, zigzagStyle, showZigZag) =>
    start = waitForConfirmation ? 1 : 0
    abcd_pattern = false

    if array.size(zigzagpivots) >= 6 + start and showZigZag

        d = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 0)
        dBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 0)
        dDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 0)

        c = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 1)
        cBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 1)
        cDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 1)

        b = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 2)
        bBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 2)
        bDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 2)

        a = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 3)
        aBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 3)
        aDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 3)

        x = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 4)
        xBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 4)
        xDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 4)

        y = array.get(zigzagpivots, start + 5)
        yBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, start + 5)
        yDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, start + 5)

        highPoint = math.max(x, a, b, c, d)
        lowPoint = math.min(x, a, b, c, d)
        dir = c > d ? 1 : -1
        abcdDirection = a < b and a < c and c < b and c < d and a < d and b < d ? 1 : a > b and a > c and c > b and c > d and a > d and b > d ? -1 : 0
        abcRatio = math.abs(c - b) / math.abs(a - b)
        bcdRatio = math.abs(d - c) / math.abs(b - c)
        
        if b < highPoint and b > lowPoint
        //ABCD Classic
            if abcdClassic and abcRatio >= 0.618 * err_min and abcRatio <= 0.89 * err_max and bcdRatio >= 1.2 * err_min and bcdRatio <= 1.667 * err_max//and abcdDirection != 0
                abcd_pattern := true
                array.set(wmLabels, 0, true)
            else
                array.set(wmLabels, 0, false)

        cancelW = false
        if abcd_pattern[1] and x == x[1] and a == a[1] and b == b[1] and c == c[1]
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 0))
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 1))
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 2))
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 3))
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 4))
            line.delete(array.get(wmlines, 5))
            cancelW := true
            cancelW

        if abcd_pattern
            ab = line.new(y1=a, y2=b, x1=aBar, x2=bBar, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_solid)
            bc = line.new(y1=b, y2=c, x1=bBar, x2=cBar, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_solid)
            cd = line.new(y1=c, y2=d, x1=cBar, x2=dBar, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_solid)
            ac = line.new(y1=a, y2=c, x1=aBar, x2=cBar, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_dotted)
            bd = line.new(y1=b, y2=d, x1=bBar, x2=dBar, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_dotted)
            RT = line.new(y1=d, y2=d, x1=dBar, x2=dBar+20, color=zigzagColor, width=2, style=line.style_solid)
            array.set(wmlines, 0, ab)
            array.set(wmlines, 1, bc)
            array.set(wmlines, 2, cd)
            array.set(wmlines, 3, ac)
            array.set(wmlines, 4, bd) 
            array.set(wmlines, 5, RT)
            array.set(wmtype, 0, dir)
            test= line.get_y1(RT)
            if close > test*1.001
                line.delete(RT)
    pattern = abcd_pattern and not abcd_pattern[1]
    pattern

zigzag(zigzag1Length, zigzagpivots1, zigzagpivotbars1, zigzagpivotdirs1)
zigzag(zigzag2Length, zigzagpivots2, zigzagpivotbars2, zigzagpivotdirs2)
zigzag(zigzag3Length, zigzagpivots3, zigzagpivotbars3, zigzagpivotdirs3)
zigzag(zigzag4Length, zigzagpivots4, zigzagpivotbars4, zigzagpivotdirs4)
wm_pattern1 = detect_harmonic_pattern(zigzagpivots1, zigzagpivotbars1, zigzagpivotdirs1, wmlines1, wmlabel1, wmtype1, wmLabels1, zigzag1Color, zigzag1Width, zigzag1Style, showZigZag1)
wm_pattern2 = detect_harmonic_pattern(zigzagpivots2, zigzagpivotbars2, zigzagpivotdirs2, wmlines2, wmlabel2, wmtype2, wmLabels2, zigzag2Color, zigzag2Width, zigzag2Style, showZigZag2)
wm_pattern3 = detect_harmonic_pattern(zigzagpivots3, zigzagpivotbars3, zigzagpivotdirs3, wmlines3, wmlabel3, wmtype3, wmLabels3, zigzag3Color, zigzag3Width, zigzag3Style, showZigZag3)
wm_pattern4 = detect_harmonic_pattern(zigzagpivots4, zigzagpivotbars4, zigzagpivotdirs4, wmlines4, wmlabel4, wmtype4, wmLabels4, zigzag4Color, zigzag4Width, zigzag4Style, showZigZag4)
```

Comment: When using:

test= line.get_y1(RT)
if close > test[1]*1.001
line.delete(RT[1])

it works somehow, but it still doesn't work for all recent ABCDs